# Rename file where it was extracted

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a VBA macro that renames a file. I have the full path where this file exist but I want to rename this file independent from its location.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim sFileName As String, sNewFileName As String

    sFileName = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\text.txt"    
    sNewFileName = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\test1.txt"    
    If Dir(sFileName, 16) = "" Then MsgBox "File not found", vbCritical, "Error": Exit Sub

    Name sFileName As sNewFileName 'rename file

    MsgBox "file has been renamed"
End Sub
```

I mean if you extract the archive with this Excel file and `text.txt` file and start it, it will find `test.txt` and rename it independent from its location.

Comment: sorry pal are you saying that you would like to rename the file and not have the the full path within the name?

Comment: yes, may be i should chek dir where file was extracted? but idk how it's looks on VB

Comment: The phrase '*start it*' worries me; are you trying to rename a file that you have open in an Excel application instance or are you trying to rename a closed file then open the file under the new name? The former cannot be done; it is a SaveAs operation not a rename.

Comment: my problem already solved. i want that file will renamed after starting excel file. Now my code do what i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `ThisWorkbook.Path` which gives you the path of the workbook you are using. So if your txt file is in the same directory you can use something like this:

```
sFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\text.txt"  
sNewFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\test1.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

When the excel file location is the same as the text file location, you don't have to write the direction path.

Just write the filename without its direction path:

```
sFileName = "test.txt"    
sNewFileName = "test1.txt"
```

Comment: if i do like this it show me an error that file not found